# Pass string parameters to the model construct in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

What is the best way to pass some not predifined string to model construct in Magento 2 with di.xml?
I have an api class which requires incoming params like service url, login and license key which i want to take from config section.

Comment: Can't you just inject in your class and instance of the config model and then read the values from the config?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but i want to keep api class independent from config class and just pass required information to construct.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you cannot inject a dynamic value through `di.xml`. From my point of view, if you need in your class a value from config, this means that your class depends on the config class. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be, you dont do this.
You have at least a data Object.

But Maybe you are more searching for the Configuration parts already existent in Magento1. You can use them like [here](https://github.com/Cotya/AuthenticationModule/blob/011d324a9a8d4ecedd741637d744f89b0418e4db/Controller/Index/Login.php#L65) and like in Magento1 you can create a default entry for this configs, so you dont need to add a real input field in the system config.